# Getter Setter Java, Passing Private Variables

Tags: java, getter-setter

I have the following class City

```
public class City {

    public static boolean walls[][];
    public static int width, height;
    public static Human people[];
    public static ArrayList<Zombie> zombies = new ArrayList<Zombie>();
```

A random map is created (walls serves to define the buildings, people is populated in City and one zombie is created in City). There is also class Human and class Zombie

```
public class Human {
int x;
int y;
int d;

public Human(int x, int y, int d)
{
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.d = d;
}
```

Both Zombie and Human contain logic that decide their movement around the map. Therefore, they need access to walls, people, and zombies in City to navigate. The program runs fine with them being static, but anytime I create a new City (to reset the program), it freezes up and I assume it's because of the static variables. I tried making them private, and creating getter and setter methods in City and calling them from Human and Zombie, but it always says that I cannot call non-static methods in a static way.
Example would be:

```
public int peopleLength(){ //in City
    return people.length;
}

City.peopleLength() //in Human
```

Could let me know what I'm doing wrong or give me a push in the right direction? Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

```
if(StdDraw.isKeyPressed(32)){
world = new City(MAX_X,MAX_Y,80, 400);
}
```

So when the space bar is pressed, the map is cleared and redrawn. Sometimes it will work for 2 or 3 times, but most of the time it just goes to a black screen and does not display anything.

Comment: "it freezes up" is not a clear description of *exactly* what happens. Having the variables static is certainly a bad idea (it won't matter how many instances of `City` you create), but it shouldn't make anything freeze.

Comment: I highly suggest starting with the Oracle Java tutorials in order to understand these basic components of the language. I can think of exactly zero reasons you'd be using `static` fields here.

Answer (score 1):

Either:

- Make the variables non-static and private, then add getter and setter methods for them, or
- Add a static method on City called reset() that resets the variables to their initial state

I'd go the first route.

Answer (score 0):

Create an instance of City using the new keyword.

```
City gotham = new City();
```

Then you will be able to reference the `gotham` object in a non-static context.